# Call to undefined function mb_internal_encoding() in My Goddady hosted website

Tags: php, laravel-5, ini

When I upload my Laravel website and configured in godaddy VPS server I started getting following error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\mb_internal_encoding() in /home/wwwideportal/ideinvoice/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php on line 43
```

I googled about it and got to know that Its a problem in php.ini file of my current hosting so , I created another php.ini file and uploaded in the public_html folder

then I did phpinfo in my browser and checked its showing that the file has been uploaded fine for php.ini and I have placed following code in it

```
extension=php_mbstring.dll
```

but still I am getting the same error

Here is my website [**link**](http://www.ide-portal.com)

Can any one tell me if I am missing any thing

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this package exist on machine?

Comment: @SafoorSafdar yes I updated my php.ini file but i donot know if the package exist or not

Comment: Create a text file, e.g. using notepad or any other text editor: `<?php

phpinfo();

?>`

Comment: @Samuel yes I have done that it shows my php.ini file being used properly.

Comment: Do you mean that you see mbstring module installed?

Comment: @Samuel Can I see that ? , here is the file http://www.ide-portal.com/phpinfo.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see it from  http://ide-portal.com/phpinfo.php,

`mbstring` module is not installed on you server.

If it was installed, it would be displayed on your `phpinfo` page like that:

[image]

Please follow [mbstring installation manual](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.php) to install it on your system.

Thanks

Comment: But the installation is not in my control its the Godaddy server

Comment: and when I call them they say they cant do anything about this . They are saying its your code error

Comment: Just request them to install missing module. It's their job AFAIK.