# PHP 7 - error in function mb_convert_encoding

Tags: php

My knowledge of PHP is limited, so I searched the solution for this problem before, but I couldn't fix it.

Upon upgrading PHP to version 7, a script is returning the error:

> Call to undefined function mb_convert_encoding()

Which refers to the line:

```
 echo "<td>" . mb_convert_encoding($row['teste'],'utf-8', 'iso-8859-1') . "</td>";
```

So, removing the function to:

```
echo "<td>" . $row['teste'] . "</td>";
```

Will remove the error, but now the characters are like:

```
Gest�o or�amental
```

Is there another function I could use?

Comment: you need to install/enable `mbstring` extension

Comment: Hi, thanks. How do I do that? Ask the host? Any further specifications?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mb\_convert\_encoding error: Call to undefined function mb\_convert\_encoding()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37441150/mb-convert-encoding-error-call-to-undefined-function-mb-convert-encoding) + [this might also help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204437/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mb-detect-encoding) and [this might also help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266396/mb-convert-encoding-undefined-function-while-mbstring-is-enabled) (Side note: Thumbs down on your research effort!)

Comment: Well if you don't have rights to modify php config files or install something then probably you need to ask the host

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your php.ini file and uncomment `extension=php_mbstring.dll`.

*mb_convert_encoding* is also supported in PHP 7, so it should work. It's probably an extension problem.

Answer (score 1):

The function [`mb_convert_encoding()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) is provided by the [Multibyte String (`mbstring`)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) PHP extension that apparently is not installed or enabled on your system.

If your PHP runs on Windows then the extension is installed but not enabled. Find the [`php.ini`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php) configuration file (check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13984456/4265352) for guidelines in case you cannot find it), identify the line that reads

```
;extension=php_mbstring.dll
```

(the `.dll` suffix might not be present) and uncomment it (i.e. remove the semicolon from the line start).

On Linux, use the package manager of your distribution (`apt`, `yum`, any graphical tool you use to install software, etc), search for `php7-mbstring` (or just `php-mbstring`) and install it. There is no need to edit any configuration file, the package manager does all the needed configuration.

No matter the OS, after this step restart the web server.